# Get properties of a class from unnitest

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I want to access from Unittest the attributes of a class that configures the path and name of a project.

In this class I use a constructor, getter and setter methods of the respective mentioned attributes and a method that receives the name of the project to be defined (if it does not receive any value, it defaults to 'foo').

Class that configures the path and name of the project: Config.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class Config:

    def __init__(self):
        self._basedir = "C:/Users/example"
        self._name_project = None

    def set_project(self, project_name=None):
        if project_name is None:
            self.set_name_project = "foo"
        else:
            self.set_name_project = project_name

    @property
    def get_basedir(self):
        return self._basedir

    @property
    def get_name_project(self):
        return self._name_project

    @get_name_project.setter
    def set_name_project(self, name_project):
        self._name_project = name_project
```

Import the above class into my unittest file: Test.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest
from Config import Config


class Test(Config, unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Config.set_project(self)

    def test_000_set_project(self):
        print(Config.get_basedir)
        print(Config.get_name_project)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING))
  File "C:\Python\lib\unittest\main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Python\lib\unittest\main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "C:\Python\lib\unittest\main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
  File "C:\Python\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\Python\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\Python\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 198, in loadTestsFromName
    inst = parent(name)
TypeError: Config.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Process finished with exit code 1

Empty suite
```

I want to print the following:

```
"C:/Users/example"
foo
```

Thanks. Greetings.

Comment: You are using the class instead of an inctance of `Config`. You have to create an instance of `Config` in `setUp` and use that. These are instance properties, not class properties.

Comment: I tried using an instance of the class in setup (as you suggested), but got the same error

Comment: I didn't notice that you use multiple inheritance in the test class - that won't work. Just derive from `TestCase` and construct your `Config` test object in `setUp`.